# Take hostages/take people hostage

Tags: sentence-meaning

They've taken 10 hostages at a supermarket.

They've taken 10 people hostage at a supermarket.

Could some please tell me if there is a difference between the two sentences?

Comment: What sort of context do you need to use this expression?  Can you show why you think there is or is not a difference?

Comment: Unless all or any of the hostages in the first sentence are animals, or fashion-store dummies, there is no difference.

Comment: "they have taken" sounds better to me.

Comment: In terms of meaning there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, in this situation, the meaning is the same.

But in general, “to take someone hostage” does not involve guns and threatening to kill people. For example “Once you buy a printer from X, you have to buy their expensive ink. They are taking their customers hostage”.